# Getting selected radio button in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried lot's of solutions here before actually make this question but none of them has worked for me.

I've tried to use `onclick` handler, tried to get by input name, tried `getElementId`, tried `elementClassName` also i tried to loop them `var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++` none has worked for me!

## Logic

1. My radio buttons will append to view based on ajax action
2. I select any of this radio buttons
3. And i want get values of this selected radio button

## Code

This is how my radios append `I made it short to be clean and easy to read`

```
success:function(data) {
        $('.shipoptions').empty();
        $('.shipoptionstitle').empty();
        $('.shipoptionstitle').append('<h6>Select your preferred method</h6>');
        $.each(data.data, function(key, value) {
          $.each(value.costs, function(key2, value2) {
            $.each(value2.cost, function(key3, value3) {
              // number format
              var number = value3['value'];
              var nf = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
                  maximumFractionDigits:0, 
                  minimumFractionDigits:0
              });
              var formattedNumber = nf.format(number);
              // number format
              $('.shipoptions').append('<ul class="list-form-inline"><li><label class="radio"><input type="radio" name="postchoose" data-code="'+value['code']+'" data-service="'+value2['service']+'" value="'+ value3['value'] +'"><span class="outer"><span class="inner"></span></span>'+ value['code'] + ' - ' + value2['service'] + ' - Rp ' + nf.format(number) + ' - ' + value3['etd'] +'</label></li></ul>');
            });
          });
        });
} //success function ends here
```

> Now I want to get selected radio button values of `data-code` ,
>   `data-service` and `value`

**For the temporary please just help me to get those values in console, later I'll fix the printing part myself.**

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SOLVED

```
$(function() {
        $(".shipoptions").on('change', function(){
            var radioValue = $("input[name='postchoose']:checked");
            if(radioValue){
                var val = radioValue.val();
                var code = radioValue.data('code');
                var service = radioValue.data('service');
                alert("Your are a - " + code + "- " +service+ "- " +val);
            }
        });
    });
```

I needed to get a higher class of my radio buttons `.shipoptions`

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio" name="postchoose" data-code="'DC11'" data-service="'DS22'" value="'V33">

var dataCode = $('input[name="postchoose"]:checked').data('code');
var dataService = $('input[name="postchoose"]:checked').data('service');

var selectedVal= $("input:radio[name=postchoose]:checked").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this jQuery Method.

```
$("input[type='radio']").click(function() {
 var radioValue = $("input[name='postchoose']:checked").val();
 var dataCode = $("input[name='postchoose']:checked").attr('data-code');
 var dataService = $("input[name='gender']:checked").attr('data-service');
 console.log(dataCode);
 console.log(dataService);
 console.log(radioValue);
});
```